# windows phone 8.1 database general questions

Tags: windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-8.1

I'm new to WP8.1 developing.

My application is using now a SQL CE database in isostore - my `DBConnectionString` - `"isostore:/SpaceQuiz.sdf"`, and everything works properly.

But here I have some questions:

1) If my `sdf` file is in `isostore` - it will be added to my xap file after deployment?

2) I want to add manually some data to this database (about 1000 rows, exemplary scheme - `ID | NAME | ISDONE | TIME`). 
Some cells in this database will be updated by my application (`ISDONE | TIME`). Also in future, I want to add next 1000 rows for example. What is the best approach to achieve this? How to prevent to restart data in my `sdf` file?

Comment: You cannot install a file to isstore, you must copy during initial launch, and by checking if the file already exists, you can prevent overwriting it. I have a number of posts on my blog for example: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/01/windows-phone-local-database-tip.html (and more http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/07/windows-phone-sql-server-compact.html )